# How to import team site in share-point 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, export, import

I have a team site that includes a calendar, workflow, list ,... . I've taken it export. import it on the another team site. Finally, the success Import.But in a time of 5 warning Import log.and when I want to record a new event on the calendar, I get an error : **file not found**

**Summery export log:**

Progress: Export completed.

Finish Time: 4/12/2015 2:42:26 PM.

Duration: 00:00:24

Total Objects: 701

Finished with 0 warnings.

Finished with 0 errors.

**Summery import warning log:**

Warning: File cannot be deleted will try to append the file instead.
*** Inner exception:
Cannot remove file "v4.master". Error Code: 158.

Warning: There can only be one instance of this list type in a web.An instance already exists.

Warning: User or group 12 cannot be resolved.

Warning: User or group 11 cannot be resolved.

Warning: User or group 1 cannot be resolved.

**Summery import log:**

Progress: Import completed.

Finish Time: 4/13/2015 10:18:12 AM.

Duration: 00:02:25

Total Objects: 408

Finished with 5 warnings.

Finished with 0 errors.

**Error when adding a new event in calender:**

[image: Error when adding a new event in calender]

Comment: Please attach log files on the error, and also try to read through your post and see if you can make it more clear what you have done and how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the master page that was set with the template is the same master page that is set to the new team site.

If this doesn't work, save the site as a template instead (located in the site settings, under look and feel; make sure sharepoint publishing feature is turned off and you will see "save site as template") and click "include content".